# JPQL Query working in testing, not in production

Tags: postgresql, jpql, h2

I have two Entities related by a `ManyToMany` and I want to select them via a named Query. This works in my test (with a H2 DB set up) and throws exceptions at runtime (with postgresql set up). Other than the H2 and PG I am hard pressed to find differences between test and production.

The Entities and the Query look like so (abbreviated):

```
@Entity(name = "Enrichment")
@Table(name = "mh_Enrichment")
NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "findByLink",
    query = "SELECT e FROM Enrichment e INNER JOIN e.links l WHERE l.link in (:links)") })
public class EnrichmentImpl  {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "enrichmentId")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;
  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(name = "mh_EnrichmentLinks", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "EnrichmentId",
          referencedColumnName = "enrichmentId") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "Link",
          referencedColumnName = "link") })
  private List<Link> links;
}

@Entity(name = "Link")
@Table(name = "mh_enrichment_link")
public class LinksImpl {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "link", length = 1024)
  private String link;
}
```

Upon running the query with a String value in production I get:

```
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = bigint
Hinweis: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
Position: 215
Error Code: 0
Call: SELECT t1.enrichmentId FROM mh_enrichment_link t0, mh_EnrichmentLinks t2, mh_Enrichment t1 WHERE ((t0.link IN (?)) AND ((t2.EnrichmentId = t1.enrichmentId) AND (t0.link = t2.Link)))
```

Any ideas what's wrong? It is the query, isn't it? 
The query is supposed to retrieve a list of Enrichments that are related to the given link.

**Update #1**
As requested: the tables in the DB look as follows:

For entity `Link`

```
CREATE TABLE mh_enrichment_link
(
  link character varying(1024) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT mh_enrichment_link_pkey PRIMARY KEY (link)
)
```

For entity `Enrichment`

```
CREATE TABLE mh_enrichment
(
  enrichmentid bigint NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT mh_enrichment_pkey PRIMARY KEY (enrichmentid)
)
```

For the relation **(See answer, this was where it went wrong)**

```
CREATE TABLE mh_enrichmentlinks
(
  link character varying(1024) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT mh_enrichment_link_pkey PRIMARY KEY (link)
)
```

Comment: It looks like the types of the columns in the join table doesn't match with the type of the column they refer to in Link and Enrichment. Check your table definitions.

Comment: I did. But as far as I understand it they are correct. The running test confirm that. Table `Link`s column link is of type character varying anyways.

Comment: Why don't you show us the definition of each table? Also, what is this LinksImpl entity, and where is the code of the Link entity?

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. Class `LinksImpl` implements the `Link` entity (table `mh_enrichment_link`). Code is in the post. Also I'll update the post with what the three tables I see in the DB.

Comment: Post your real code, and your real table definitions. LinksImpl doesn't implement Link, so the code is wrong. And you posted two different definitions of the same table. Finding a problem with only incorrect information provided is a waste of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was fixed by dropping all related tables and having JPA regenerate them. Table definitions didn't match Entity definitions. 
Thats also the quite obviously the reason why the test worked and the production didn't. In testing the tables are generated on runtime, in production they existed already (with an outdated definition).
Side note: The query is correct and does what it should.